# How to prevent laravel foreach showing double value and sorting ascending

Tags: laravel, loops, foreach, laravel-blade

In my blade i use three nested `foreach` loops, since I'm doing 3 queries for database in controller. And it showed me doubled data and it sort ascending.

here's my code :

**1. Blade (with foreach)**

```
               @foreach ($keranjang as $purchase)
                    @foreach ($pelanggan as $member)
                        @foreach ($produk as $product)
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">{{ $purchase->ID_pembelian }}</th>
                                <td>{{ $product->nama_produk }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $member->nama_pelanggan }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $purchase->tgl_pembelian }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $purchase->jumlah }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $purchase->harga }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $purchase->total }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $purchase->status }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
```

**2. Controller with 3 queries**

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('keranjang', [
            'keranjang' => $pembelian = Pembelian::where('ID_pelanggan', auth()->user()->ID_pelanggan)->get(),
            'pelanggan' => $pelanggan = Pelanggan::where('ID_pelanggan', auth()->user()->ID_pelanggan)->get(),
            'produk' => $produk = Produk::find(Pembelian::where('ID_pelanggan', auth()->user()->ID_pelanggan)->get('ID_produk')),
            "title" => "Keranjang"
        ]);
    }
```

**3. And here is the result :**
[image: Table View]

.
.
but, i want it to be like below (not showing double data and not sorting ascending):
[image: Table View]

And i change the controller and use first(), it showed me the right first data i want which `kandang kucing` besides `pet bowl`, but both of the value is the same :(.

```
'produk' => $produk = Produk::find(Pembelian::where('ID_pelanggan', auth()->user()->ID_pelanggan)->get('ID_produk')->first()),
```

[image: Table View]
how do i fix it? is something wrong with my controller or my foreach in blade?

Comment: You can upvote the answer if you think it can help beginners working with Laravel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the edit. helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from your data it seems like you are fetching related data from 3 different tables, what you can do here is make use of one of Laravel's many features, known as Many-to-Many relation that works with pivot tables.

### Step 1 - Making Pivot Table

Learn [How to make a pivot table](https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/)

```
php artisan make:migration create_alpha_beta_table --create --table=alpha_beta
```

While creating the pivot table we don't need a model so its just a migration with a conventional name of related tables in alphabetical order, for example if the two related tables are menu and restaurant the table will be `menu_restaurant` with `menu` first and `restaurant` second according to their alphabetical order. This can't be `restaurant_menu` hence, `alpha_beta` not `beta_alpha`.

### Step 2 - Define Relationships

Once you are finished creating pivot you can simply define relation in each tables Model, for example:

`Alpha.php` Model:

```
public function beta() {
    return $this->hasMany(Beta::class);
}
```

`Beta.php` Model

```
public function alpha(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Alpha::class);
}
```

### Step 3 - Use the Relationship

Once you are finished, defining the relationship, you can simply  call the relationships using `with()` on your query builder and the data will be in a nice and clean format ready to use inside a single loop, Now to call it inside the `AlphaController.php`

````
```
Alpha::where('id',1)->with('beta')->get()
```
````

this will give you following result:

```
alpha[
    id => 1,
    name => 'some really alpha name',
    another_col => 'data',
    beta => [
        id => 3,
        alpha_id => 1,
        name => 'some really beta name',
        another_beta_col => 'data'
    ]
]
```

See how you have beta combined with alpha where the foreign key is matched.